# Avoiding C++ explosive instantiations of template classes that take int parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a C++ class:

```
template<int N>
class Text {
    public:
        Text() { }
        char _buf[N];
};
```

It simply encapsulates a C string.

Now, let's say I write a method that will take another `Text` object, with a length `M` and copy its contents into this object.

```
template<int N>
class Text {
    public:
        Text() { }
        char _buf[N];

        template<int M> void copy(const Text<M> &t) {
            strncpy(_buf, t.cstr(), N - 1);
            _buf[N - 1] = '\0';
        }            
};
```

Is this going to cause an explosion of duplicated object code where the only difference are the constants `N` and `M` used, especially if I use this `copy` method with objects that have lots of different `N` and `M` ?

Since the method itself doesn't depend on `M` at all, is there another way to approach this such that I avoid this explosion of duplicated object code?

Comment: What will mostly happen is that all calls to copy will be inlined so that no real functions will be emitted at all. This sounds like a premature optimization which should be just ignored.

Comment: Actually, no. My object code has doubled in size from the use of just a couple values of N and M. I'm trying to keep object code size down.

Comment: Are you compiling it with optimization flags?

Comment: Yes, use the \[expletive censored\] `std::string`.

Comment: @n.m. This appears to be a fixed-length, null-terminated, non dynamically-sized string. `std::string` isn't a solution.

Comment: @Barry So what? Change your design to use std::string, that's all.

Comment: Whats about a base class with a pure virtuelle Methode getbuf() and use the base class as parameter to the copy function.

Comment: Note: if `M` < `N`, you'll be copying from memory past the end of the `_buf` array in 't' (assuming `cstr` just returns a pointer to `_buf`). This is going to cause undefined behavior.

Comment: You do compile with the optimize-size flag, right?

Comment: @Ana Did you check that the function is really generated and contained in the object file? It could be that the increase is the result of inlining the function.

Comment: @n.m. This is for an embedded system that supports a C++ subset. No STL. Dynamic memory avoided at all costs. Make more sense?

Comment: It's not really C++ then, you should have said that right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious approach is to factor the common bits into a base class, e.g.:

```
class TextBase {
public:
    char* text;
    int   n;
    TextBase(char* text, int N): text(text), n(N) {}
    void copy(const TextBase &t) {
        strncpy(this->text, t.text, n - 1);
        this->text[n - 1] = '\0';
    }  
};
template<int N>
class Text: public TextBase {
public:
    Text(): TextBase(_buf, N) { }
    char _buf[N];
};
```

It trades object size for a potential improvement in code size. It must be obvious because it was the first thing coming to my mind while still waking up. Instead of traveling in terms of a base taking the parameter in a type-erase form avoids the need for extra storage, e.g. (this approach came to my mind when being a bit further away from waking up):

```
template<int N>
class Text {
public:
    Text() { }
    char _buf[N];
    operator char const*() const { return this->_buf; }
    void copy(char const* source) {
        strncpy(this->_buf, source, N - 1);
        this->_buf[N - 1] = '\0';
    }
};
```

Comment: `TextBase(char*,int)` is pretty dangerous. You just leave memory management to the user. Could use plain old `char*` just as well.

Comment: @n.m.: just make the `TextBase` construct `protected`. If you want to make sure that `TextBase` is really just used from `Text<N>` you could make the constructor `private` and `template <int> class Text` a `friend`. All of that is beside the point of the question asked, though.

Comment: Not sure you are getting a usable class this way. How do you return these things from functions, etc.

Comment: @n.m.: You'd return `Text<N>` with `N` being a suitable constant expression. The whole point of the base class is to provide the `copy()` interface as a member while not depending on the template parameter as it doesn't really use it.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the solution could be a base class with a pure virtual method to get the buffer.  There are no additional attribute required and `_buf`could be privat.

Something like this:

```
class TextBase {
public:
    virtual const char* cstr() const =0;
};

template<int N>
class Text: public TextBase {
public:
    Text() { }
    void copy( TextBase &t) {
      strncpy(_buf, t.cstr(), N - 1);
     _buf[N - 1] = '\0';    }  

protected:
  virtual const char* cstr() const {
    return _buf;
    };
private:
    char _buf[N];
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think C++11 introduced [`extern template`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template) to do this:

> An explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) prevents
>   implicit instantiations: the code that would otherwise cause an
>   implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation
>   definition provided somewhere else in the program (typically, in
>   another file: this can be used to reduce compilation times)

However, for your use-case, you would to explicitly instantiate Text::copy for all combinations of N and M, so it doesn't seem feasible and Dietmar's answer would be a better alternative.